# Django page redirect based on locale url

Tags: redirect, django-views, django-urls, url-pattern, django-localeurl

Lets say we have a page:

http://www.example.com/cs/department/category/

I am using django-locale for internationalization.

How am I going to achieve that if somebody type:

http://www.example.com/en/department/category/

EN instead of CS it will redirect.

I achieve this by commenting out the other languages like this:

[image]

But what I would like to do is keep them there uncommented. What would be the proper redirect in urls.py or views.py that only 'CS' is working. DE & EN would be redirected. If you dont understand I can clarify more.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fast and lazy solution can be:

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def myview(request):
    newurl = 'define your new url here'
    if not 'cs/' in request.get_full_path():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(newurl)
```

Comment: But if I have lets say 20 views, I have to add it to every single one of them?

Comment: Yes in this case but you can also create redirect in urls.py ` from django.views.generic import RedirectView ` then in your urlpatterns add ` url(r'^bad_url/$', RedirectView.as_view(url= 'good_url')), ` hope it helps